# SAP Fiori Routing Issue in Cross App Navigation

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to fix a major issue in another developer's code. Explaining the scenario and issue below. Any help towards a solution would be appreciated, thanks!

**Apps and screens involved in the issue:**
**Custom Fiori App 1 :** Screen 1 (single view) , Screen 2 (master & detail view)
**Custom Fiori App 2 :** Screen 1 (master & detail view)

**Navigation To:** In App1, on click of a button in Screen 1's footer, navigation is happening to Screen 2 in the same app. Now on click of a button in Screen 2's footer, the navigation is happening to App 2. - this is working fine.
**Navigation back:** On click of the back button in the master page header, the navigation is supposed to happen to Screen 2 in App 1 since the user just came from there. But it is not working that way. It is going to Screen 1 of App1. Here is the code of the back function:

```
onBack:function()
{
  this.oRouter.detachRouteMatched(this.handleNavTo, this, this);
  var oCrossAppNavigator = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");
  oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
  target: {semanticObject : "ZManageAccount", action: "displayMangeAccount" }
  });
}
```

Comment: Your second routing code, navTo method check what's the third parameter

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with this navigation before as well.

I was able to make it work by providing a `shellHash` instead of `semanticObject` and `action`. (The target is still the same.)

```
onBack: function () {
    this.oRouter.detachRouteMatched(this.handleNavTo, this, this);
    sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").toExternal({
        target: {
            shellHash: "ZManageAccount-displayMangeAccount"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried shellHash like you suggested, but no change in the navigation behaviour :-(